# How to retrieve the import name of a module from its pip requirements name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

After parsing requirements.txt, lets assume this is the list of pip modules:

```
>>> modules_req = ['beautifulsoup4','django-nose','ujson']
>>> for module in modules_req:
...     __import__(module)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named beautifulsoup4
```

How can we retreive the import name of these modules i.e. `bs4` for `beautifulsoup4`, and `django_nose` for `django-nose`, for example ?

Comment: Can the downvoter explaint the close vote and the reason for downvote please ?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but why don't you include in `modules_req` directly the modules import names instead?...

Comment: @IronFist , because as I mentioned, that has been parsed from a requirements.txt file. The above example can be a case of environment testing before deployments.

Comment: Well then, first thing that come to my mind is to build a `dict` for that...mapping required module:import name...

Comment: @IronFist  Lets assume requirements.txt is the only information available about the module, hence the question of how to retrieve the actual name. Else, it creates a requirement of having another file apart from requirements.txt to put actual module names.

Comment: i'm guessing this is a means to an end. what are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: @second, this is a unit test to check that all modules specified in requirements.txt are installed. I know that is doable through the difference between `pip freeze` and requirements.txt file as well, I am looking for a way by which actual import names can be tested.

Comment: what are you hoping to gain over just comparing to pip freeze?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i'm not sure this is what you actually want to do, but for installed packages you might get some mileage out of querying `pkg_resources` for package info:

```
$ pip freeze
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
```

.

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> list(
        pkg_resources
        .get_distribution('beautifulsoup4')
        ._get_metadata('top_level.txt')
    )
['bs4']
```